# On double click Exit from app in jquery mobile + phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I am building my app using phonegap.I have Write a Code for on double click of back button of phone app should be close but its not working i have write a code.

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready',onDeviceReady, false);      
    },


onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        var exitApp = false, intval = setInterval(function () { exitApp = false; }, 1000);
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (exitApp) {
                clearInterval(intval)
                (navigator.app && navigator.app.exitApp()) || (device && device.exitApp())
            }
            else {
                exitApp = true
                history.back();
            }
        }, false);
    },


receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};
```

so whats is Problem in it because it is act as its default back going functionality. i am using phone gap version 3.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

@vatsal,
double click on the screen is the default for zoom. Using the back button that way is not a good way to exit. Most people use a dedicate [exit] button. You might consider the same.

FWIW, you do NOT need the `e.preventDefault();` for that event.

You can look at my notes and source code on events here:
https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-Events-test
and here:
https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-PhysicalButton-test/blob/master/NOTES

Jesse